# What's the intel cpu for consumer with best value?

Tags: processor

I'm looking for an Intel CPU with higher core and suitable for programming. Aspects are as follows,

Aspects:

- Frequency
- Cores/Threads
- Can run multiple Virtual Machines ( I think this needs RAM)

I don't care power consumption.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to have just built a new PC with Intel i9-9900K
it has 8 core and 16 thread for $700 CAD.
I think it's best for the buck if you are looking for higher core counts and thread counts as well.

Comment: cool. Will this CPU be overheat?

Comment: @LiMing So far it works fine for me. Averaged 80C when under really heavy load.